# What's wrong with the manual refresh web part option?

Tags: web-part, 2013, ajax

I have a task list in SharePoint 2013 that I have enabled the AJAX manual refresh button for. This option can be found by editing the list web part, then going to AJAX options and then ticking "Show Manual Refresh Button".

Unfortunately, whenever I click this button, the timeline is duplicated, for example, if I were to click the button 4 times, I would end up with 5 timelines (including the original one).

Does this happen for everyone else? Is it a bug in SharePoint 2013 or perhaps something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a sharepoint bug, timeline isn't really friendly with ajax http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c02681a4-8e7f-41c3-a5a2-9c22079ea684/new-sp-timeline-web-part-not-ajax-friendly?forum=sharepointdevelopment